# SQL Select Where Date <= To date

Tags: sql, date, date-difference

Hi I am a newbie in SQL syntax.

I would like to have a query results in SQL using the below syntax.

```
Select * from tblSales where duedate <= todate
```

But when i run it was an error.

Please advise me for the correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS (server/system) are you running this on? Also please include text of the error

Comment: Are `duedate` and `todate` columns in the `tblSales` table?

Comment: r u checking duedate against todays date?

Comment: yes im checking duedate vs todays date  if todays date <= duedate then view results

Comment: sql server is the DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from(
select datediff(day,getdate(),Duedate )as Diff,
SInumber ,InvoiceNo,Customer ,Tradedate,PaymentTerms,Duedate,Amount   
from tblSales )as D where DIFF <= '10'
```

This is the Query i want..and it solved!

Answer (score 1):

In your question the RDBMS is not mentioned..

For SQL Server your query should be

```
Select * from tblSales where duedate <= GETDATE()
```

where `GETDATE()` return the current system date and `duedate` should be a `date datatype.`

If you are using oracle to get current system date you can use `SYSDATE`

Comment: diff between todate vs duedate = result if result <=10 then select the record

Comment: @Daryl didn't understand what is your requirement?

Comment: sorry i want this the result of this query 
    select datediff(day,getdate(),Duedate )as Diff,
    SInumber ,InvoiceNo,Customer     ,Tradedate,PaymentTerms,Duedate,Amount   
     from tblSales where DIFF <= '10'

Comment: @Daryl this result means can you explain with an example ..i didn't understand your first comment

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblSales WHERE DATE(duedate) <= CURDATE();
```

I don't test it yet. Hope it works

Comment: No curdate in sql statement

Comment: diff between todate vs duedate  = result    if result <=10 then select the record